# UIAutomation with Instruments - How to tap copy/paste buttons?

Tags: ipad, instruments, ios-ui-automation

I'm using Instruments for iOS automation and I can't seem to figure out how to tap options on the copy/paste menu.  When I do a logElementTree(),I see that we are returning a UIEditingMenu and then three elements (which correspond to options of that menu, such as copy/paste, etc..). I am attempting to place this into a variable, and then trying to "tap" that variable but I cannot get that to work.  Here is a sample of my code:

```
var target = UIATarget.localTarget();

var app = target.frontMostApp();

var window = app.mainWindow();

//This generates the highlighted text

app.dragInsideWithOptions({startOffset:{x:0.45, y:0.6}, endOffset:{x:0.45, y:0.6}, duration:1.5});

var copy = app.editingMenu.elements.withName("copyButton");

copy.tap();

Instruments returns, "0) UIAElementNil".  In addition to the above, I've also tried:

app.elements.withName("copyButton")

window.elements.withName("copyButton")
```

So, I can get the editingMenu to produce the available options, but I cannot figure out a way to tap or select one of those options.  I'm not quite sure I know how to reference those options to begin with.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should try `app.editingMenu().elements()[index].tap()` where index is the index of the option you want to tap from the array of elements returned. I got my one working this way.

Answer (score 0):

Hey.
First of all, I was always using `.elements()` not `.elements`... but it is JS, so it may be invoking function that is assigned to object property..?
Anyway, maybe this edit menu is not internal window of the app, but it is system level menu, that is invoked, when you do the drag? If that is true, try:

```
UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp().elements().withName("copyButton").tap();
```

But as I see in [apple reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/UIAutomationRef/UIAutomationRef.pdf) your version with calling `app.editingMenu()` should be fine...
Maybe try calling buttons by position, and you will see which respond:

```
UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp().editingMenu().elements()[0].tap;
UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp().editingMenu().elements()[1].tap;
UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp().editingMenu().elements()[2].tap;
```

You should find position of correct one this way. When you have it's position you can check its properties by `button.logElement();`.  With this inf you  you should be able to switch back to `.withName` method instead hardcoded position.

Comment: Hey Yoosiba, I greatly appreciate the time you've taken to respond.  Unfortunately, I still cannot get it to work, despite your suggestions.  Back to the drawing board I go.

Answer (score 0):

I did this similar to yoosiba but with editingMenu element names.
Using Xcode 4.5.1 and device running iOS 6.

Using Alex Vollmer's excellent [tuneup_js](https://github.com/alexvollmer/tuneup_js) for target, app and vtap().
Otherwise you can use UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp() and tap().

NOTE: vtap() will delay and retry tapping. Without this you may need to add your own delays.

```
 // tap in textFieldA to see editingMenu.
 app.mainWindow().textFields()["textFieldA"].vtap();
 app.editingMenu().elements()["Select All"].vtap();
 app.editingMenu().elements()["Copy"].vtap();
 // must delay before attempting next tap
 target.delay(2);

 // ... navigate to different section of the app

 // tap in textFieldB to see editingMenu.
 app.mainWindow().textFields()["textFieldB"].vtap();
 // paste clipboard contents copied from textFieldA into textFieldB
 app.editingMenu().elements()["Paste"].vtap();
 target.delay(2);
```